# typo3 directory is not writable

Tags: typo3

I am moving a typo3 based webserver and after copying the files and databases, I get an error in the Installation tool:

`Directory /typo3conf/ext is not writable`

There are others, too. I copied them as root, so they are flagged as owned by root:root. Do I have to set them to my accessing user or is there another problem?

Cheers,

Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to determine which user you have to use with apache/nginx, just let them create a file. (Installtool -> fix folder structure -> this will create some folders)

After you created you can see which user/group you need.

This might be helpful: http://fideloper.com/user-group-permissions-chmod-apache

Regards

Sebastian ;)

Answer (score 0):

> There are others, too. I copied them as root, so they are flagged as owned by root:root. Do I have to set them to my accessing user or is there another problem?

Oh yes :-) Never let root own anything that is facing public. Your apache/nginx user might be named `www-data` or similar. Make sure that it is that user, that owns the files and folder and have write access to it

Comment: Let me suggest that you read through this security guide https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/SecurityGuide/GuidelinesAdministrators/FileDirectoryPermissions/Index.html